# Issue with updating custom object with parameters from Lightning App

Tags: apex, soql, lightning

I'm new to salesforce development. I've developed a lightning component from which i need to insert or delete a particular entry on clicking a checkbox.
Delete if the entry exists already and insert if it doesn't

This is how my app look like

[image: This is how my app look li]

This is the client side js Controller method i'm using..

```
    updateAvailability: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var product_id = evt.getParam("product_id");
        var task_id = cmp.find('task_id').get("v.value");
        var account_id = cmp.find('account_id').get("v.value");
        var activity_id = cmp.find('activity_id').get("v.value");
        helper.updateAvailability(cmp, product_id, activity_id, task_id, account_id);
    }
```

This is the client side js helper method i'm using..

```
updateAvailability: function(cmp, product_id, activity_id, task_id, account_id) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.updateAvailability");
    console.log('task_id : ' + task_id);
    console.log('account_id : ' + account_id);
    console.log('activity_id : ' + activity_id);
    console.log('product_id : ' + product_id);
    action.setParams({
        "product_id": product_id,
        "activity_id": activity_id,
        "task_id": task_id,
        "account_id": account_id
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

and this here is the apex method in server.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateAvailability(String product_id, String activity_id, String task_id, String account_id) {
    try {
        Task_Ledger__c taskDetail;
        try{
            // delete if the entry exists already
            taskDetail = [SELECT Id, Task__c, Account__c, Action__c, Product__c, Measure_value__c FROM Task_Ledger__c WHERE Task__c = :task_id AND Action__c = :activity_id AND Account__c = :account_id AND Product__c  = :product_id AND Measure_value__c = '1'];
            System.debug('dlt');
            delete taskDetail;
        }
        catch (System.QueryException e){
            // insert
            System.debug(e);
            taskDetail = new Task_Ledger__c(Task__c = task_id,Account__c = account_id, Action__c = activity_id, Product__c = product_id);
            taskDetail.Measure_value__c = '1';
            System.debug('upsert');
            upsert taskDetail;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Message: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is the main component i'm using

```
<aura:component controller="TaskController" implements="force:appHostable">

    <!-- Salesforce's Lightning Design : Installed Package -->
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds0101/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
    <!-- Handle component initialization in a client-side controller -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <!-- Event for updateing Availabilty Details Page corresponding to activity Detail id  -->
    <aura:handler name="updateAvailability" event="c:updateAvailability" action="{!c.updateAvailability}" />

    <aura:attribute name="activityDetails" type="Activity_Detail__c[]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="curr_activity" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="curr_task" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="curr_account" type="String"/>

    <div class="container">
        <ui:inputText class="slds-hide task_id" aura:id="task_id" value="{!v.curr_task}" />
        <ui:inputText class="slds-hide account_id" aura:id="account_id" value="{!v.curr_account}" />
        <ui:inputText class="slds-hide account_id" aura:id="activity_id" value="{!v.curr_activity}" />

        <ul class="slds-list--vertical slds-has-cards slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">
            <aura:iteration var="activityDetail" items="{!v.activityDetails}">
                <li class="slds-list__item slds-tile__detail">
                <!-- BOF Nested Component -->
                <c:AvailabilityDetails activityDetail="{!activityDetail}" />
                <!-- EOF Nested Component -->
                </li>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
        <br/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

This is the nested component AvailabilityDetails

```
          <aura:component >
             <aura:attribute name="activityDetail" type="Activity_Detail__c"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="updateAvailability" type="c:updateAvailability"/>

    <div class="slds-grid ">
        <div class="slds-col slds-text-heading--label">{!v.activityDetail.Product_Name__c}</div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-float--right">
                <label class="slds-checkbox" for="{!v.activityDetail.Id}">
                    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="{!v.activityDetail.Id}" onclick="{!c.updateAvailability}"/>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                    <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

This is my event file

```
    <aura:event type="COMPONENT">
        <aura:attribute name="product_id" type="String"/>
    </aura:event>
```

This is js controller file for calling event

```
    ({
      updateAvailability : function(component, event, helper) {
        var product_id = event.target.id;
        var uav = component.getEvent("updateAvailability");
        uav.setParams({ "product_id": product_id }).fire();
      }
    })
```

When i check this from my developer console's 'executable anonymous window', it's working fine..

Nothing happens when i run this from the Salesforce1 app.

Logs are showing in Force.com Developer Console i click from the Salesforce1 app or from the preview app in browser but debug messages are not showing..

Is there any syntax error with the helper method or 
any issues with way the apex method is used?

When running from chrome, i get this warning message in console

```
WARNING: Action failed: todo_list$controller$updateAvailability
```

Comment: Did you check if any javascript errors show up in javascript console?

Comment: hi @Patlatus, i got this warning message  
WARNING: Action failed: todo_list$controller$updateAvailability

Comment: do you see 'task_id :' string parameter in javascript console and other javascript logs in console?

Comment: Yes.. I'm getting all of them.. 
I took them and executed from Force.com Developer console's 'executable anonymous window'.
It's working fine there..

Comment: Can you share component file as well?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava i've added the nested component in question.

Comment: Share your app file as well ?

Comment: Also client js code .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava i've added a screenshot of the app and main component with the question.. Please check now

Comment: Cool...if I could get event file.Also where are you firing event?Type of event?

Comment: Add all code exact how you have so I go more deeper here ..

Comment: @MohithShrivastava done

Comment: @MohithShrivastava any solutions?

Comment: @sreejith I am travelling ..will get back to you for sure ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35669/discussion-between-sreejith-and-mohith-shrivastava).